Is there any way to make Java static imports work in Visual Studio Code without setting "java.completion.favoriteStaticMembers" in settings?
I'm switching from JetBrains products line to the VSCode. So far the transition was smooth for JS and Python projects.
The Java support seems also ok for me, but I would like to know if the only way to support static methods imports in VSCode is through tweaking the java.completion.favoriteStaticMembers in my settings. Or is there any better workaround to make static imports work out of the box "automagically"?

What's wrong with setting that setting?

To start off, this setting should be constantly modified to add new entries there. Second, besides importing from "built-in" Java packages and popular libraries, I might want to import from project-related packages. As for me, it seems quite tedious to keep this potentially long list up to date. If I'm not mistaken, in Intellij Idea it just works out of the box. Was wondering if it's possible to replicate this behaviour in VSCode.

Hello, do you have Extension Pack for Java installed? It may be able to provide automatic hints and completions for static imports. Or use import static to import manually.

Hi, yes, I do have it installed. And it works just perfectly for normal (non-static) imports, however it does not provide hints/completions for static imports until I manually add desired package(s) to the java.completion.favoriteStaticMembers.

How about "java.sources.organizeImports.staticStarThreshold": 1,?

Came across same issue. It is very annoying to have to manually configure static imports for any static constants I define in my projects. This can and should be automatic.

Yes. Also, tried the java.sources.organizeImports.staticStarThreshold solution and it's not working, this setting is not related to the topic unfortunately.

Looks like this is a jdt upstream issue.Check this out:https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3564
